# Matching new line in TCL - regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a variable

```
set a "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Proto     Source Address                         Pkt-Cnt    Start
                 Destination Address                    Byte-Cnt
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       UDP       150.1.1.2                              25         05/24/2021 07:07:29
                 150.2.1.2                              1150      

      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

i need to match all the values after the word UDP.
i tried this one to match the first line and it works good. But i could not get the values "150.2.1.2" and "1150" - Any help is much appreciated

```
    regexp "UDP + (\[\[:graph:]]+) + (\[\[:graph:]]+) + (\[\[:graph:]]+) +(\[\[:graph:]]+)"  $a match data1 data2 data3 data4
```

Comment: ***Always put your REs in braces*** unless you _need_ Tcl substitutions in the middle of them. Otherwise all the extra backslashes will cause you no end of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the similar logic and add two more capturing groups separated with `\s+` (one or more whitespaces):

```
regexp {UDP\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)}  $a match data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6
```

Note that `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars and `\s+` matches one or more whitespace chars.

See the [online Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/NgU4js) with `UDP` declared as a variable:

```
set a "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Proto     Source Address                         Pkt-Cnt    Start
                 Destination Address                    Byte-Cnt
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       UDP       150.1.1.2                              25         05/24/2021 07:07:29
                 150.2.1.2                              1150      

      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

set b "UDP"
regexp "$b\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)" $a match data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6
puts "$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5, $data6"
# 150.1.1.2, 25, 05/24/2021, 07:07:29, 150.2.1.2, 1150
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, this works but if i substitute a variable for UDP it does not match as in,  regexp {$b\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)}  $a match data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6

Comment: @GiridharanL It was not clear from your question, I updated to use `UDP` as a variable.

Comment: i need to use like set b UDP - will this work too ?

Comment: @GiridharanL Sure, see my demo, it uses `set b "UDP"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do it, but I think this RE is what you ought to use:

```
{UDP\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)\s*([\w/]+ [\w:]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)}
```

It's enclosed in braces because otherwise there's a *lot* of extra backslashes!

The essential pieces:

1. `UDP` — Marker text
2. `\s*` — Whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc)
3. `([\d.]+)` — Captured digits and dots (the source address)
4. `\s*` — Whitespace
5. `(\d+)` — Captured digits (the packet count)
6. `\s*` — Whitespace
7. `([\w/]+ [\w:]+)` — Captured start timestamp (with only a single space in the middle)
8. `\s*` — Whitespace (this includes the newline; newlines are whitespace by default)
9. `([\d.]+)` — Captured digits and dots (the destination address)
10. `\s*` — Whitespace
11. `(\d+)` — Captured digits (the byte count)

In use:

```
regexp {UDP\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)\s*([\w/]+ [\w:]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)} $a -> source packetCount start destination byteCount
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, this works but can i substitute a variable instead of the Marker text as in "b" has the value UDP , regexp {$b\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)\s*([\w/]+ [\w:]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)} $a -> source packetCount start destination byteCount

Comment: If you want a variable there, it's probably easiest to insert it with the `format` command so that you're still not fighting backslashes: `regexp [format {%s\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)\s*([\w/]+ [\w:]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\d+)} $b] $a -> source packetCount start destination byteCount` (Also, be aware that the thing you put in there needs to be a well-behaved RE in its own right that doesn't capture anything and doesn't have a terminal anchor. `UDP` is an example of what's good, and `foo(bar)$` is bad in several ways.)